AppImage giving APPRUN_ERROR: No such file or directory
I am trying to build an AppImage for my Flutter application; this used to work as expected, but after updating to Ubuntu 24.04 (not sure if this is relevant or not) the resulting AppImage is showing:
APPRUN_ERROR: No such file or directory

when I try to execute it. Interestingly, the executable in the AppDir does run successfully before I run AppImageBuilder, but after it states:
bash: ./shackleton: cannot execute: required file not found

but ldd doesn't show any missing libraries.
My Github action is here:
https://github.com/hobleyd/shackleton/blob/main/.github/workflows/ubuntu.yml
and the AppImageBuilder.yml is here:
https://github.com/hobleyd/shackleton/blob/main/AppImageBuilder.yml
Would anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong, please?
Cheers,
David
